# Excel - open a Word doc, find a text and move start to next word

Tags: excel, ms-word

I'm trying to write a VBA code in excel that must work in this way:
1- open a word doc in a specific path
2- find into the word doc a specific text
3- copy from the text the following word/words

As example the word text is: "This document expires on 24 June 2025. A succeeding document will be published on the website of the company Micros"
Searching for "expires on" the macro must return 24 June 2025

My actual code:

```
Sub Test()
Dim wordapp As Object
Dim worddoc As Object
Dim Rng As Range

    File = "C:\Users\Io\Company.docx"
    Set wordapp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    wordapp.Visible = True
    
Set worddoc = wordapp.Documents.Open(File)

// now the word file has been opened

// trying to search for the content     

    With wordapp.Content.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Execute FindText:="expires on: ", Forward:=True, _
                 Format:=False, Wrap:=wdFindStop
        Fnd = .Found
    End With

// I found in the doc the content


// this part of selecting the next words does not word
    If Fnd = True Then
     With Rng
        .MoveStart Unit:=wdWord, Count:=2
        .MoveEnd Unit:=wdSentence, Count:=1
        ISIN = Rng
        End With
    End If



End Sub
```

probably the issue is the setup of the range that I'm not able to do,
please help. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Some basic Word VBA you can adapt:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = "This document expires on [0-9]{1,2} [JFMASOND][anuryebchpilgstmov]{2,8} [12][0-9]{3}>"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Format = False
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Execute
  End With
  If .Find.Found = True Then
    .Start = .Words(5).Start
    MsgBox .Text
  End If
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```